# Custom off topic dialog allows incomplete sentences from the prefill

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close, on-hold

In [these](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here?noredirect=1#comment376_111) [two](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/whos-luke-always-interfering#comment20705_9296) comments, the user has been able to submit a custom off topic reason that says:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about

While it's not really feasible to check for complete sentences, can the system at least detect when the user does not add anything of significance to the custom off topic reason and act accordingly? Maybe it can open up a dialog saying "Please enter a custom comment", or let the vote through without leaving the autocomment.